# How do I enable NGINX' http_stub_status_module on 16.04?

Tags: drivers, software-sources, nginx

How do I enable the NGINX http_stub_status_module on Ubuntu 16.04? It doesn't appear to be available for use and I read elsewhere that it requires a recompile which I'd like to avoid for the purpose of maintaining NGINX through the package repos.

Comment: The [build flags](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/nginx/wily/view/head:/debian/rules#L48) for 15.10 indicate that all nginx packages have that module enabled; and I'd think 16.04 uses the same settings. Are you sure it isn't available?

Comment: @muru,  I haven't tried, just assumed I'd need to install it separately like I do for so many Apache modules. I'll check that out.

Comment: I suppose I should say: welcome to nginx! Modules are enabled at compile time and the packages provide nginx compiled with sets of modules, not individual modules.